# Flutter change Localization programatically

Tags: flutter, localization

I followed  the new Flutter Tutorial (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) for Localizations and it works like a charm.

But I have a question:

Is it possible to change the Locale when the user taps a button?

```
MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
      supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
        title: "MyApp",
        theme: ct.theme,
        home: MyHomePage(),
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your wished locale to the `MaterialApp`. If it is null, the app will take the system language. In that way you can wrap your `MaterialApp` in an `InheritedWidget` for changing the locale from anywhere in the widget tree. It's not an elegant but a simple solution. My `InheritedWidget` looks like this:

```
class MyI18n extends InheritedWidget {
  final Function(Locale) _localeChangeCallback;

  const MyI18n(
      this._localeChangeCallback,{
    Key key,
    @required Widget child,
  })  : assert(child != null),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  static MyI18n of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<MyI18n>();
  }

  void changeLocale(Locale locale) {
    _localeChangeCallback?.call(locale);
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(MyI18n old) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

You can also save the locale in the `InheritedWidget` for using it in `updateShouldNotify` :)

Your `MaterialApp` will look like this:

```
MyI18n(
  (locale) => setState(() => this._locale = locale),
  child: MaterialApp(locale: _locale, ...),
),
```

For using it: `MyI18n.of(context).changeLocale(locale)`

There are other ways for changing the locale but in my opinion this one is really simple. (You can do it the same way but with less code by using a `Provider` and/or a `Bloc`.)

Comment: okay, thank you for the quick answer! 
I implemented your proposal. But I have a question on this:
How can I update my Local from a widget inside the tree? How can I refer to the M18 "Widget" and call the Method changeLocal?

Comment: Use MyI18n.of(context).changeLocale(locale) with any context of your widget tree. For a more detailed explanation of InheritedWidget you can read the follwoing article: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html

Comment: What would be the best practice solution to load the Locale code, that I have saved in my SharedPrefs?

Either in My App before returning the inherited widget or directly in the inherited widget?

Comment: I set it before the widget builds. In any other way the text would change after the first frame.